# Got below error while trying to cover my excel test cases to testing-xml

Tags: apache-poi, testng, appium, automator

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.getCellType()I
    at com.codoid.products.fillo.CommonExcelUtil.getColumnNames(CommonExcelUtil.java:86)
    at com.codoid.products.fillo.SelectExcelUtil.runSelectQuery(SelectExcelUtil.java:84)
    at com.codoid.products.fillo.Select.getRecordset(Select.java:61)
    at com.codoid.products.fillo.Connection.executeQuery(Connection.java:64)
    at com.neo.suiteCreater.XLSReader.getTests(XLSReader.java:25)
    at com.neo.suiteCreater.createSuite.main(createSuite.java:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to update the version of fillo. Current version might be older one with deprecated code.